# Java 8 Function<T,T> replacement

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

I have

```
Function<String, String> myFunction;
```

Is there any other predefined signature that indicates a function that **"converts"** object into the object of the **same type**?

I believe there should be dedicated one for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [UnaryOperator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`UnaryOperator<T>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html) - this does exactly this thing.